# Update coordinates on geopackage with shapefile

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-joins, update

I have a geopackage file that has all the information about certain items but the coordinates need to be updated. I'm using an old Leica 1200 GPS to get the new coordinates and giving the same ID to these points that they have in the geopackage.

What is the best way to update the coordinates in the geopackage with the ones from the shapefile generated by the GPS knowing that the ID will be same, I've been using excel's VLOOKUP function for this but would like to know if there is a way to do it inside QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not trivial to do that with ogr2ogr and ogrinfo. The shapefile must be inserted into GeoPackage first but it can be deleted once the geometries have been updated.

**Source data**

jointest1 contains 2 points

```
  ID (Integer) = 11
  POINT (77 33)

  ID (Integer) = 22
  POINT (15 35)
```

jointest2 contains also two points

```
  ID (Integer) = 22
  POINT (5 25)

  ID (Integer) = 0
  POINT (3 2)
```

The aim is to update feature 22 -> POINT (5 25) and keep feature 11 as POINT (77 33). Feature with ID=0 that does not exist in jointest1 should not be added.

Layer jointest1 is in GeoPackage "jointest.gpkg" and jointest2 is shapefile. First import also jointest2 into GeoPackage.

```
ogr2ogr -append -update -f gpkg jointest.gpkg jointest2.shp
```

Next use ogrinfo with -sql parameter for running the update command. The syntax for the command is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite.

```
ogrinfo -sql "update jointest1 set geom=(select geom from jointest2 where ID=jointest1.ID) where exists (select geom from jointest2 where ID=jointest1.ID)" jointest.gpkg
```

Check what we have now in jointest1

```
ogrinfo jointest.gpkg jointest1
…
  ID (Integer) = 11
  POINT (77 33)

  ID (Integer) = 22
  POINT (5 25)
```

Now we can drop the jointest2 table and vacuum the database. If you just drop the table from a SQLite database the file size remains the same until you vacuum the database. It is not dangerous if you don't vacuum, you will just have a bit larger database file on disk.

```
ogrinfo jointest.gpkg -sql "drop table jointest2"
ogrinfo jointest.gpkg -sql "vacuum"
```

Comment: Note that you have the possibility for inconsistencies (I see that a lot at work!) when your attributes also contain numeric coordinates, e.g. LAT and LON or something like that. These will need to be updated too!

Comment: Who needs lat and lon coordinates if there is a database with geometry field? But updating them would mean just two more SQL update queries.

Comment: from how often I see them everybody and their dog needs them... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Updating coordinates is hard and would probably require some advanced fiddling. I would recommend instead to:

- Open both files in QGIS
- Join the attributes from the GeoPackage layer to the Shapefile layer using the ID
- Save that layer as a new GeoPackage

That way you don't have to touch geometry processing but only the attribute data which is way more easy.